# Upgrading IIS 7 to 8 found exception "The input is not a valid Base-64 string"

Tags: iis

My application is running normally on IIS7 but when I upgraded to IIS 8, I am getting this exception

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string

As it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  ??

Comment: What's the input that causes the error ?

Comment: when i tried to enter user name and password but the same application is running normally on iis 7 when i deployed it on iis 8 give me this exception

Comment: @Vivian. Please make sure that you are using correct .NET runtime (2.x or 4.x) in app pool.

Comment: i am using .net v4 and check my pool everything is good same as on iis 7 but when  move on to iis 8 i get this error